# É possivel definir o tipo de retorno de uma Promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Bom dia. Gostaria de saber se é possivel definir o tipo de retorno de uma Promise com typescript. Preciso disso pois tenho uma função que retorna uma promise para uma consulta no banco de dados e preciso que quando a consulta seja realizada o retorno seja um objeto (no meu caso um produto), porem o then() retorna um tipo unknown. Segue em anexo um exemplo do código que retorna a promise:

```html
getProtudo(idProduto) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this.bancoSrc.banco.find({
        selector: {type: 'produto', _id: idProduto},
        fields: ['_id', 'descricao', 'referencia']
       }).then((result) => {
        this.produto = JSON.parse(result);
        res(this.produto);
       }).catch(err => {
        rej(err);
       });
    });
  }
```

E aqui vai o código que utiliza essa promise:

```html
this.pickerCtrl.create(opts).then((picker) => {
  picker.present();
  picker.onDidDismiss().then(async (data) => {
    const col = await picker.getColumn('quantidade');
    this.produtoSrc.getProtudo(idProduto).then((prod) => {
      const qtd = col.options[col.selectedIndex].value;
      const pedido: Produto = new Produto(prod._id, prod.descricao, qtd, 10);
      this.listaPedido.add(pedido);
    });
  });
});
  }
```

Não consigo criar o objeto porque quando tendo usar o prod._id no create do meu objeto, dá o seguinte erro: ": "Property '_id' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Dessa forma que postei acima esta funcionando. Mas agora tenho outra duvida, o meu objeto esta chegando como undefined quando tento acessar as propriedades dele. Função:

```
getProtudo(idProduto) {
    return new Promise<Produto> ((res, rej) => {
      this.bancoSrc.banco.find({
        selector: {type: 'produto', _id: idProduto},
        fields: ['_id', 'descricao', 'referencia']
       }).then((result) => {
        res(result);
       }).catch(err => {
        rej(err);
       });
    });
  }
```

Se eu exibi-lo atrás do console apresenta a seguinte resposta:

```
docs: Array(1)
0: {_id: "produto-1", descricao: "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", referencia: "KADETTE"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar com isso? Grato desde já.

Comment: Gustavomgu, o seu método `getProtudo` está retornando um array, por isso você não está conseguindo acessar a propriedade `_id` diretamente. Já que a sua função só deveria retornar um objeto, ao invés de fazer `res(result)`, faça `res(result[0])`. Talvez você precise fazer o `JSON.parse` também como você estava fazendo no primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Tem razão, era um array mesmo, para conseguir acessar usei result.docs[0]. (Tive que fazer isso porque estou resgatando a informação de um banco de dados NoSQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só precisa fazer o uso de `generics` para definir o retorno da `promise`. No caso de uma promise que resolve um número, o tipo do seu retorno seria `Promise<number>`.

Como você está retornando um objeto, você pode definir as propriedades do seu objeto resolvido na assinatura da própria função:

```
getProtudo(idProduto): Promise<{_id: string, descricao: string, referencia: string}> {

}
```

Ou se você já tem o tipo desse objeto definido, você pode utilizar alguns recursos do TypeScript para gerar o tipo dinamicamente a partir de uma interface base:

```
// exemplo de interface
interface MeuTipo {
    _id: string
    descricao: string
    referencia: string
    outraInformacao: number
    maisInformacao: string[]
}

// Apenas as propriedades que foram buscadas no banco de dados
getProtudo(idProduto): Promise<Pick<MeuTipo, '_id' | 'descricao' | 'referencia'>> {

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou bem, porem ainda tive um problema aqui. Eu não estou usando uma interface mas sim uma classe, daí ele apresenta uma mensagem de erro: 'Pick' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Comment: Usar classe ou interface não deveria fazer nenhuma diferença para o `Pick`, talvez se você postar a definição da sua classe eu possa checar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Por favor, edite a sua pergunta. Interpretar os comentários sem formação fica meio difícil. E inclua a declaração da sua classe `Produto` também.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e removi os comentários com código não formatado.